# TextMate 2 Bundle creation

Tags: macos, textmate

In TextMate 2, how can I create a new Bundle?

I´m using a programming language which so far doesn't have a bundle (so no syntax highlighting, snippets and so on). TextMate 1 used to have a Bundle Editor, but where do I get started in TextMate 2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of this writing, the beginning steps are:

1. Go to **Bundles (menu)** > **Edit Bundles…**
2. Press **⌘N** to create a new bundle.
3. The bundle gets saved in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles`; you may wish to right-click on the saved bundle and choose **Show Package Contents** to see what's inside your bundle.

Further info can be found e.g. [here](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/locating-bundles/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/380371/how-do-i-create-a-new-snippet-in-textmate-2).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to copy an existing bundle, rename it, and edit it.

Here’s the official manual on that: [TextMate Manual → Bundles](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles).

> #### 5.2 Editing Default Bundles / Items
>
> Some of the default items may not be to your exact liking, for example
>   the coding style in snippets may differ from yours, so you may want
>   other tab triggers, key equivalents, or similar modifications.
>
> If you edit a default item the difference will be stored in
>   `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles`. These are then merged
>   with the default version so your changes will be effective even after
>   upgrading TextMate. All new items you create also end up in this
>   location.
>
> Bundles or bundle items which you install by dragging them to TextMate
>   or double clicking will be installed in `~/Library/Application
>   Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles`. Editing these will also result
>   in only the differences being stored in `~/Library/Application
>   Support/TextMate/Bundles`, meaning that if you later get a new version
>   of this third party bundle, you can safely install this one on top of
>   the old one (by dragging it to TextMate) and again your changes will
>   be preserved.
>
> If you want to discard local changes then currently the only option is
>   to delete these from `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles`.

---

Alternatively, here’s a more visual guide (lots of screenshots): [**How to create a TextMate bundle**](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2010/09/30/how-to-create-a-textmate-bundle/).

Comment: I believe this pertains to Textmate 1.